# Regex to match empty string or pattern

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to build an application that reads lines of csv text from the network and inserts it into sqlite db.  I need to extract all strings that appear between commas, including empty strings.
For e.g a line of text that I need to parse looks like:

```
"1/17/09 1:23,\"Soap, Shampoo and cleaner\",,1200,Amex,Steven O' Campbell,,Kuwait,1/16/09 14:26,1/18/09 9:08,29.2891667,,48.05"
```

My code snippet is below , I figured I need to use regex since I'm trying to split the line of string at "," character but the comma may also appear as part of the string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^|[^,"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)`)
    txt := "1/17/09 1:23,\"Soap, Shampoo and cleaner\",,1200,Amex,Steven O' Campbell,,Kuwait,1/16/09 14:26,1/18/09 9:08,29.2891667,,48.05"

    arr := re.FindAllString(txt, -1) 
    arr2 := strings.Split(txt, ",")     
    fmt.Println("Array lengths: ", len(arr), len(arr2)) 
  
}
```

The correct length of the split array in this case should be 13.

Comment: You're saying "read lines from a csv file" but you want to use a regexp? Why not just use the csv package?

Comment: Regex is usually the wrong tool. It's definitely the wrong tool here. Use a CSV parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63453585/regex-to-match-empty-string-or-pattern#comment112204489_63453585) and [Flimzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63453585/regex-to-match-empty-string-or-pattern#comment112207180_63453585) said, regex isn't the right tool here. And since you're not specifying that we should use regex as the tool to extract data from your string, here's a snippet on how you'd extract those from your string and fit the result you're looking for:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var testdata = `1/17/09 1:23,"Soap, Shampoo and cleaner",,1200,Amex,Steven O' Campbell,,Kuwait,1/16/09 14:26,1/18/09 9:08,29.2891667,,48.05`
    var reader = csv.NewReader(bytes.NewBufferString(testdata))
    var content, err = reader.Read()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(content)) // 13
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was legacy code that I was working with . It was reading a stream from the network and parsing the lines to search/replace text. The  idea was to change the code to insert the stream in a sqlite d/b instead.  The csv package seems to work but will there be an extra data copy involved if I write the buffer to the csv reader and read the resulting records ?

Comment: It shouldn't, the `csv.NewReader` uses a io.Reader as a argument, so it shouldn't matter if it's a BufferString, a file or any other readable resource.